# How many permutations of the sequence 1, 2, 3...N where none of the first K numbers in the original sequence is in it's place?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, inclusion-exclusion

For the sequence `1, 2, 3 ... N` there are of-course N! permutations.
But for a given K, where *1 < K ≤ N* how many permutations are there given none of `1, 2, 3, ... K` is in the 1st, 2nd, ... Kth position correspondingly.

I have seen somewhere that the solution is

`(N-K)! - C[K,1] * (N-K-1)! + C[K,2] * (N-K-2)! + ... + C[k,k] * (N-2K)!`

But I don't quite understand it. A little help?

Comment: It looks like application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to me. It starts by counting all possible permutations (including the ones violating the conditions), then removes those which are violating one condition, adds back those which violated two of them simultaneously (since they were removed twice) and so on. That being said, I'd expect the factorial terms to be $N!$, $(N-1)!$, down to $(N-K)!$ instead of $(N-K)!$, ... unless I misunderstand the problem statement. What value do you expect for $N=4$, $K=2$?

Answer (score 0):

$\binom{k}{r}(n-r)!$ counts the number of permutations of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ such that at least $r$ objects among the first $k$ objects are fixed. Applying inclusion-exclusion principle, the number of permutations where every $i$ th element (where $1\le i\le k$) is not fixed is $$n!+\sum_{r=1}^{k}\left( (-1)^{r}\binom{k}{r}(n-r)!\right)$$